# Storing workspace variable in GUI for use by other push buttons. MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have just started making a basic GUI with GUIDE, so far I have one push button that I am using to call a .m file I wrote earlier called sortData.m

When run outside of the GUI, sortData.m puts a matrix called "merge" into the workspace, but when I run sortData.m inside the GUI nothing happens.

I need "merge" to get stored somewhere so that my next push button can use it to output figures... how can this be done? Thanks

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
sortData
```

Comment: is `sortData` a _script_ or a _function_? ... If it is a script, then you have to convert it to a function, so you can capture a return value when you call the function.

Comment: it's a script, thanks for pointing that out I'll have a go

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result inside your `GUI` for later use, i.e:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.mydata = sortData;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Or you can retrieve the data from workspace when you need it, i.e:

```
my_merge = evalin('base', 'merge');
% do anything with my_merge here
% note that nothing affects matrix merge in workspace
```

Comment: for some reason adding those two lines stopped sortData from running at all :S

Answer (score 0):

1. modify sortData-> make it a function by adding this as the first line:

   function merge = sortData(..)
2. modify the callback:

   function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
   merge = sortData
   handles.merge = merge
   guidata(hObject, handles);

later, within any callback that gets the handles-struct, you can retrieve the data with *handles.merge*.
Check the documentation for more about data-sharing, see (for example):

- [TMW-newsreader](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/248625)
- [TMW: documentation guidata](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html?searchHighlight=guidata)