# Matlab GUIDE - Running a script from a push button and using the workspace variables

Tags: matlab

I have a script which takes in a bunch of data and outputs a results matrix called "results".

I can get the push button to run the script, but "results" is nowhere to be found...

I have a second script which uses "results" to do further analysis, which I want the second push button in the GUI to trigger.

```
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
processFirstSet
```

processFirstSet is the first script, but it's not clear to me how to proceed from here

Comment: See MATLAB's documentation for [Sharing Data Among Callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question [Storing workspace variable in GUI for use by other push buttons. MATLAB GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910132/storing-workspace-variable-in-gui-for-use-by-other-push-buttons-matlab-gui#comment51836517_31910132) (just with another script in button3 instead of button1. I strongly recommend you read the link from @excaza comment above and stop using _script_ within GUI. If you're only interested in one output `results`, package your script into a function.

Comment: well I still don't get it, that's why I asked again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes back from your script will remain inside the GUI environment, so when the scripts ends, the pushbutton call will end and your return data "results" will be lost.

Either pass it on into the next function while staying inside the GUI and continue using the data right there (then later saving it for example) eg

```
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  results = processFirstSet
  processSecondSet(results)
  %do something else
```

or export to the matlab workspace using assignin (eg)

```
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  results = processFirstSet;
  export_name = 'my_data';
  assignin('base',export_name,results);
```

Here some basic hints, as I said in the comments.
Take your scrip, and turn it into a function by making a new file and using this format (replace the areas marked with your script). Save it with the same name firstStepFunction.m

```
function [results] = firstStepFunction(c)
  a = 1; %your script here
  b = 7; %your script here
  results = a+b+c; %your script here
end
```

you can then run this function from the command line by typing firstStepFunction(2) and it will return 10 as ans into the workspace. (c) behind the function name is the function argument, if you don't need to be flexible with your function, you can leave that empty, which might be the case if you just copy past your script into the function outline.

If you now use that inside the gui pushbutton function, you need to assign the return value results (which in the example is 10) to a variable or it will get lost, for example:

```
results = firstStepFunction(2);
```

now you have results stored in a variable inside your pushbutton function. And now you can export it as above, so the whole example in this case (make sure you saved the firstStepFunction) would be

```
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  results = firstStepFunction(2);
  export_name 'my_data';
  assignin('base',export_name,results);
```

Comment: thanks. I'd like to add it to the workspace, but when I copy and paste your second 4 lines in place of mine it doesn't run :S it says "attempt to run script processFirstSet as a function"

Comment: processFirstSet is a function (the one you supplied above in your question). If your script is not in form of a function, read up on functions in matlab, as others said. I will edit my answer though to get you started.